# C# System.MissingFieldException on an existing field

Tags: c#

I am using C# 4.7.2 an PRISM Unity 6.2.0

I got a public class like this

```
public partial class MyClass
{

    public static string MyFirstString = "MyFirstString";

    public static string MySecondString = "MySecondString";

}
```

The strings are used to register types

```
public void Initialize()
{
    RegisterObjects();  
}

private void RegisterObjects()
{
    container.RegisterType<object, SomeClass>( MyClass.MyFirstString );

    container.RegisterType<object, SomeOtherClass>( MyClass.MySecondString );
}
```

container is an IUnityContainer, Initiliaze() is a member of IModule (from PRISM)

SomeClass is registered without any problems. But SomeOtherClass can not be registered. A System.MissingFieldException is thrown on MyClass.MySecondString.

Everything is public, the build succeeds, one can even navigate to MySecondString by pressing *F12* (in Visual Studio).

What could cause this exception?

Comment: Did you test replacing MyClass.MySecondString with the literal "MySecondString"? If this throws the same exception, you are looking at the wrong place.

Comment: Make sure to completely clean and rebuild your project. Check your build paths. Sounds like you maybe getting an old dll. Also, make sure SomeOtherClass actually contains the property "MySecondString" and that you didn't misspell it (usually why i see this).

Comment: @Klaus Güttner I did replace it. Now the application runs into the next error (that never happend to show up before) Something is entirely wrong with that application.

Comment: @Ryan Pierce Williams I deleted all files manually and a cleaned the projects multiple times by using visual studio und did builds and rebuilds over and over. Nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have multiple versions of the DLL loaded in your cache.  Use "gacutil -l " to see how many version are loaded in your cache.  You can use "gacutil -u " to remove all versions.